# jquery mobile changing page from java script is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile app. I want to change "pages" (divs with data-role=page) with javascript, and not only using anchor with href. 
In the onclick event in javascript I wrote the next line:

```
window.location = 'index.html#item32';
```

and it worked.
But when I tried to dinamically create a url, like that:

```
var NextIndex = (CurrIndex + 1) % arr_length;
    var Url = 'index.html#item' + NextIndex;
    window.location = Url;
```

Nothing happend. I didn't get any error in the chrome console tab.
and when I debugged, the Url was exactly as the one that worked.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the jQM pagecontainer widget's change method: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change ?

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. nothing happens. and no error in the debug.
Also changed the name of the "Url" var, thought that it might triggered something.

Comment: This is how you use the pagecontainer: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/e5zt5Ldv/